# Writing a Color sARGB array to a WriteableBitmap

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an two-dimensioanl array of sARGB colors (System.Windows.Media.Color) describing what I want to write in a WritableBitmap.  The array is the same width and height than the expected bitmap.  The problem is that, as long as I can see, the WritePixels Method of the WritableBitmap expects an array of integers.  How do I convert my colors to said array?

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of the elements in the array? If they are `Color` values, the `Color` structure has a `ToArgb` method that returns the color as an integer.

The `WritePixels` method accepts a one-dimentional array of most any simple type, like byte, short, int, long. For an ARGB format each pixel needs four bytes, or one int.

Edit:
As you have `System.Window.Media.Color` values, you can use the `A`, `R`, `G` and `B` properties to get byte values for the components of the color:

```
byte[] pixelData = new byte[colorArray.Length * 4];
int ofs = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < colorArray.GetLength(1); y++) {
   for (int x = 0; x < colorArray.GetLenth(0); x++) {
      Color c = colorArray[x, y];
      pixelData[ofs++] = c.A;
      pixelData[ofs++] = c.R;
      pixelData[ofs++] = c.G;
      pixelData[ofs++] = c.B;
   }
}
```

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Color doesn't have a ToArgb method.  An in sARGB color space all the values are a single.

Comment: I didn't know which color structure you used (the System.Drawing.Color structure for example has a ToArgb method). Se my edit above for how to get the color components.

Comment: I used the one in WPF System.Windows.Media.Color that handles sARGB color space, not just ARGB.

Comment: The System.Windows.Media.Color value can be created from any color space, and you read the sRGB color values using the A, R, G and B properties. (There is no sARGB color space.)